# How can i reach next page after logging in via POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest

In the next codelines i try to log into a moodle system via POST. This works quite well, if i leave the two lines commented, i can see the webpage after login. But when i try to navigate to the next webpage, which is in a protected area, I always get to see the login-page.

So my question is, how can i navigate to the protected page an display it in the webview?

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[defaults stringForKey:@"loginpage"]]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",
                 [defaults stringForKey:@"username"],[defaults stringForKey:@"password"]];
    NSLog(@"Post is: %@",post);

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSLog(@"postData is: %@",postData);

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSLog(@"postLength is: %@",postLength);

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSLog(@"request is: %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);


    [self.webview loadRequest:request];

    //if i do not comment the next two lines, the loginpage is displayed in the webview.
    //Otherwise the correct page with username after login is displayed.
    //request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[defaults stringForKey:@"displaypage"]]];

    //[self.webview loadRequest:request];

    NSLog(@"Done");
```

Comment: what you are trying to do, you want to create a web browser for your self. or something else. here what are you doing is only loading some request in webview.

Comment: I'm trying to write a simple app, that logs the user into a moodle-system, and display a protected site, so you don't have to always start your webbrowser on your smartphone and do these clicks for yourself.

Comment: Is there a way you can confirm on the server that you have indeed logged in? Also, I've used NSUTF8StringEncoding for the post parameters, don't know if that could be an issue.

Comment: Yes, i could search after a special string in the answer i.e. But when i run the code i am definitly logged in, because I can see the correct page after the login in the webview. I just need to navigate to the next page, but I don't know how. When i run the next request, I'm logged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loadRequest method is asynchronous, meaning that when the method returns, it's very likely that it hasn't finished loading the first web page.
So when you uncomment those two lines, probably the second request is being executed while the first one hasn't finished.

You should execute the second request in the UIWebViewDelegate's webViewDidFinishLoad: method.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the delegate in the storyboard, the following code did the job:

```
    -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[defaults stringForKey:@"displaypage"]]];
    [self.webview loadRequest:request];
}
```